Amazon Aurora data compression
I am looking for a way to compress old tables data which is mainly used for read purpose in aurora mysql(innodb). Looks like mysql does support compressed table/index format and unfortunately aurora does not.
Please share any other methods or recommendations to achieve data compression. This is mainly to save cost.

This question is for the dba sister site of SO as it is not about programming, but about managing a database.
